# format and change sql output xls file column heading in unix sql script

Tags: sql, oracle, csh

I wanna change my column heading and format it to ceratin size so all dat can be seen in xls output file which is generated through sql script.. For example if the name of column is Lst_name.. on my xls column heading i wanna change it to Last Name and ceratin size of that cell so full last name is visiable.. i have one of the column that has data in certain cell only number(234) and in certain both number and alpha (2B4) how can format them so it will be all align on right side of cell

Comment: Are you talking about generating a CSV file that you'll view in Excel? You can't determine column alignment (i.e. right-aligned) from the Oracle end if so, and you'll have problems with mixed content fields starting with zero (e.g. 0B4 would lose the leading zero in Excel). Both can be dealt with by importing data into Excel but that's not an Oracle question. You can make the headings work but not sure I understand the question enough to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Very hard to read your question.

You can alias a column name as follows:

```
SELECT LAST_NAME "Last Name", FIRST_NAME "First Name"
FROM ...
```

Except for LONG and CLOB columns, in SQL*Plus, the column sizes is defined by the length of the column, so a VARCHAR2(80) will produce a fixed width output 80 characters wide followed by the separator (generally a space).

One exception is that there is a WRAP feature which might kick in for fields over 80 characters long. Look at SET WRAP to change that.